# Provide data consistency in Cloud Foundry Java app on multiple instances and single db

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, cloud, cloud-foundry

the title explains pretty well the problem:

I'd like to deploy a Java application (that may scale on multiple instance) connected on a single MySql database.

Does Cloud Foundry provide any assistance to avoid data inconsistency?

or should I manage on my own some sort of read/write locks as a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's anything specific to Cloud Foundry about your questions.  You'd do the same thing on Cloud Foundry that you would do if you were running multiple copies of your application on servers in your own data center.

To answer your questions:

> Does Cloud Foundry provide any assistance to avoid data inconsistency?

No.  That's the responsibility of your application.

> or should I manage on my own some sort of read/write locks as a workaround?

If you're talking to MySQL, I'd say use transactions appropriately in your application.